# Getting strange translated i18next result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I am trying to insert dynamic values into translated text *and*  set these values to `bold`. However, this gives some messed up result.

These are my translation files

```
// en
{
  "common": {
    "greeting": "Hello <1>{{name}}</1> will see you in <2>{{city}}</2> !"
  }
}

// de
{
  "common": {
    "greeting": "Hallo <1>{{name}}</1> wir sehen uns in <2>{{city}}</2> !"
  }
}
```

And this is how I try to translate this with bold text and dynamic values for `city` and `name`

```
let nextCity= 'Mumbai';
let userName = 'Jane';
<Trans
    values={{ name: userName, city: nextCity}}
    i18nKey="common.greeting">
        Hello <strong>{{name}}</strong> will see you in <strong>{{city}}</strong> !
</Trans>
```

And this is the result

Hello **Jane** will see you in !

`city` is not filled, its simply blank. Hwo to fill i18next with dynamic values **and** make them bold?

I expect

Hello **Jane** will see you in **Mumbai**!

Comment: Could you indicate what should be the output? If `city` is `null` or `undefined` then it is normal if it doesn't appear in the string

Comment: @ArturoMendes I updated my Q, `city` is not undefined or anything related.

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with your logic because, from the piece of code you shared, you declare `name` and `city` but then use `userName` and `nextCity` and there is a chance that you might have transferred the value of `name` to `userName` but not done the same with the value of `city`

Comment: @ArturoMendes That was a typo on my side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick solution

You have to change the *replacement tags* in your translation files to `4` for `city` (explanation in the [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#how-to-get-the-correct-translation-string)), like this:

```
en: {
  common: {
    greeting: "Hello <1>{{name}}</1> will see you in <4>{{city}}</4> !"
  }
},
```

Check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-trans-component-example-forked-wg0s0v?file=/src/index.js).

Also, I had to add the namespace to the component for it to work but that doesn't seem to be an issue in your code (must be something with the version):

```
<Trans
  ns="common"
  values={{ name: userName, city: nextCity }}
  i18nKey="greeting"
>
  Hello <strong>{{ userName }}</strong> will see you in <strong>{{ nextCity }}</strong> !
</Trans>
```

### How to get there

From the docs *"guessing replacement tags of your component is rather difficult"* so to help you should use [*React Developer Tools*](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/react-developer-tools). Checking the children of the `Trans` component you will see the following:

```
Trans.children: [
    0: "Hello ",
    1: "<strong />",
    2: " will see you in",
    3: " ",
    4: "<strong />",
    5: " !"
]
```

And that's why you can see **Jane** but not **Mumbai**, **Jane** has the *replacement tag* `<1></1>` that corresponds to its position on the child index. To be able to see **Mumbai** you would have to change its *replacement tag* to either `<1></1>` or `<4></4>`:

```
en: {
  common: {
    greeting: "Hello <1>{{name}}</1> will see you in <4>{{city}}</4> !"
  }
},
```

**What is happening when you use `<2></2>` and why doesn't it work?** *i18next* is looking at its second children which is a plain string and finding *will see you in*, since there are no values to replace there, the resulting string is:

> Hello **Jane** will see you in will see you in !

**Why does `<1></1>` work if it does not correspond to the index of the child?** *i18next* sees two `<strong></strong>` components that it has to match with its children (one with index 1 and another with index 4), since both are `<strong></strong>` you will see no difference but if you change the first to `<i></i>` the translation string will result in:

> Hello *Jane* will see you in *Mumbai*

When the expected result would be:

> Hello *Jane* will see you in **Mumbai**

Comment: That works, but its probably the worst API I have seen... I hope there are good reasons for it to write it like this.

Comment: @four-eyes on a personal note, I have never had to use the `Trans` component, instead I have managed to cover all my requirements with the `t` function which is much simpler and clearer to use, see if it suits your needs

Comment: I use the `t` function anywhere, but this is not possible with the `t` function.